# A WPF VB.NET control which is referenced from another project is not shown in my WPF application

Tags: vb.net, xaml, reference, wpf-controls, project

I created a custom wpf control and added it to my xaml. This works. However, if I put the custom control in another project and try to include it from there, it is not visible when I run my application. The right control ("CustomViewDirectly") in the attached example is from the same project and the left control ("CustomView") from the referenced project.
How can I correctly include the CustomView / make it visible?
I use VisualStudio2012 Update 4.

Example Solution:
http://pvcell.wikispaces.com/file/view/WpfTest.zip/513722714/WpfTest.zip

Some code snippets:

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:WpfTest.Core"
    xmlns:core1="clr-namespace:Utils.Core;assembly=Utils"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
<core:CustomViewDirectly HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
<core1:CustomView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

-

```
<UserControl x:Class="Core.CustomViewDirectly"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background="Black" >
    <Button Content="Directly" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="87,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

-

```
<UserControl x:Class="Core.CustomView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">

    <Grid Background="#FFEE0D0D">
        <Button Content="Referenced" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="0,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

Comment: In your example solution, try recreating your Utils project as a "WPF User Control Library".  I'm not sure what the difference is, but that seemed to work for me.  I created Utils2, copied the Core folder from Utils, and updated project reference in WpfTest and the core1 namespace in MainWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a "WPF User Control Library" project, instead of a "Class Library" project for your custom controls.